# <input type="date"> not validating when value changes in Firefox for Android

Tags: android, html, angular, firefox, angular2-forms

When using the Firefox (versions 54 and 55) for Android or for Desktop with the `dom.forms.datetime` flag set to true. It opens a calendar modal for the user select the date. But when the user selects the date the validations are not updated and the submit button continues disabled.

**my.component.html:**

```
<input id="deadline" 
       type="date" 
       class="form-control"
       name="deadline" 
       placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" 
       formControlName="deadline">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!newForm.valid">
      save
</button>
```

**my.component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.newForm = new FormGroup({
        deadline: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}')
        ]))
    });
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Could you add a plunker demonstrating the behaviour? [here's a template to get started](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Firefox for Android only triggers a change but no input event after the user selects a date from the datepicker. The [DefaultValueAccessor in Angular relies on the input event](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L52). As a result, the value of the form control is not updated and stays `null`.

As a workaround you can add an onchange listener that calls `setValue()` of the FormControl.

**my.component.ts:**

```
    @ViewChild('input')
    private input: ElementRef;

    @HostListener('change')
    private missingInputWorkaround() {
        const formCtrl = this.newForm.get('deadline');
        if (this.isBrowserWithoutInputEvent() && this.input.nativeElement.value !== formCtrl.value) {
            formCtrl.setValue(this.input.nativeElement.value);
        }
    }

    private isBrowserWithoutInputEvent() {
        // Firefox for Android (Fennec)
        return /\(Android .+ Firefox\/\d+/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    }
```

Comment: Only needed to include that #input in the element. Edited the answer to reflect it. Thanks!